# Appcelerator Titanium : How to reduce Android Picker size?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, font-size, picker

I want to reduce the height of the Android Picker using Appcelerator Titanium. It allows me to reduce the size but then content is not visible. Moreover I found no way to reduce the font size of the picker data in titanium android.

Please let me know if anybody has faced the same problem and found the resolution.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve this. Even i have tried this but no success. If you get some success than you can share with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up with no solutions !! It is not possible to resize the Android Picker size cannot be changed. I have tried this with lots of effots and I am ending up with 0 success.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way to achieve this. The workaround I did was like this:

```
// create a custom picker using table view
// you can change its font & row size
var tbl = Ti.UI.createTableView();

// set it to OptionDialog's androidView
var op = Ti.UI.createOptionDialog({
    androidView: tbl
});
```